# Convert array php to array javascript. From a sql query (Postgres DB)

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, postgresql

i'm using a db postgres, so, i have a array of text in it, and i want get the array in php and pass to javascript. I'm trying this:

file.php

```
$sql="select array_to_json(ids) as ids from table";
$result=query($sql);
$row=pg_fetch_assoc($result)
$imgs=$row['ids'];
```

file javascript

```
var myarray='<?php echo json_encode($imgs)?>';
```

But when i do this :

```
console.log(imgs[0]);
```

i'm getting a char, and in fact, the type of variable is a string (verified with typeof in javascript). What is wrong?

Comment: are you getting an error for the missing ; in the `<?php echo json_encode($imgs) ?>` ?

Comment: try `var myarray=JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($imgs)?>');`

Comment: this should also work : var myarray=<?php echo json_encode($imgs)?>;

Comment: @redsecurity no, It was a mistake to transcribe

Comment: @jetblack Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token d in JSON at position 3... the variable has the value : "["data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2wBDAAsICAoIBwsKCQoND.................................

Comment: @M. Doe Sorry I didn't realize that you're already get JSON encoded value in your PostgreSQL query. So this should work: `var myarray=JSON.parse('<?php echo $imgs; ?>');`

Comment: @M.Doe Is this issue solved?  Did jetblack's comment fix it for you?  If so, please comment at jetblack to ask for the comment to be posted as an answer, so you can award it the green tick and this question can be laid to rest.